# Make menu items in two columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make my menu items in two columns in the center of the page. Right now they appear to be in a single horizontal line. Is there a way to achieve that using flexbox. 
Here's the code: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yCiLm

My CSS:

```
.menu-opener, .menu-opener:hover, .menu-opener.active, .menu-opener-inner, .menu-opener-inner::before, .menu-opener-inner::after, .menu, .menu.active {
  -webkit-transition: 250ms all;
  transition: 250ms all;
}

.menu-opener {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  right: 1%;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 64px;
}
.menu-opener:hover, .menu-opener.active {
  background: #231F20;
}

.menu-opener-inner {
  background: #000;
  height: .5rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
  margin-top: 1.75rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
}
.menu-opener-inner::before, .menu-opener-inner::after {
  background: #000;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: .5rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
}

.menu-opener-inner::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.75rem);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-0.75rem);
  transform: translateY(-0.75rem);
}
.menu-opener-inner::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0.25rem);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0.25rem);
  transform: translateY(0.25rem);
}
.menu-opener-inner.active {
  background: transparent;
}
.menu-opener-inner.active::before {
    background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0rem) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0rem) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(0rem) rotate(-45deg);
}
.menu-opener-inner.active::after {
    background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0rem) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0rem) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0rem) rotate(45deg);
}

.menu {
  background: #231F20;
  color: transparent;
  height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
 right: 1%;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 0rem;
  z-index: -1;
}
.menu.active {
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 2rem);
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  height: calc(100% - 1rem);
}
.menu.active .menu-link {
  color: white;
}

.menu-inner {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 4rem;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-link {
  color: transparent;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-link li {
  margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu {
    height: auto;
  }
  .menu-inner {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-link {
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  .menu.active {
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 0.5rem);
    width: calc(100% - 0.5rem);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add:

```
min-width: 50%;
```

to the .menu-link class?